Flutter onChange Not Working on My TextField
I created a re-usable textfield for my Flutter project but the OnChange method is not working with the re-usable widget. Whenever I tried creating the field directly on the project it works. I am suspecting that the value option that comes with the Textfield onChange is likely the reason for the error. Any help with a solution?
class NumberOnlyTextField extends StatelessWidget{
  final controller;
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  final bool enableTxtField;
  final Function()? onChanged;

  const NumberOnlyTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.obscureText,
    required this.enableTxtField,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 213, 211, 211)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            onChanged: (value) { onChanged; },
            obscureText: obscureText,
            enabled: enableTxtField,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                RegExp('[0-9]+.?[0-9]*'),
              ),
            ],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: hintText,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here is where it is used on another page:
      //Amount
      NumberOnlyTextField(
        controller: amountXController,
        onChanged: validateAmount(),
        hintText: 'Amount',
        obscureText: false,
        enableTxtField: true,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),


Also I wanted the Textfield to allow only integers or double but also not working. I want the textfield to accept only inputs in this format 1.12 0r 200

U are not calling ur onChanged function this why function is not working.
I did this
onChanged: (value) {
              if (this.onChanged != null) this.onChanged!();
            },

or
  onChanged: (value) {
          onChanged?.call();
        },

so NumberOnlyTextField now
class NumberOnlyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller;
  final String hintText;
  final bool obscureText;
  final bool enableTxtField;
  final Function()? onChanged;

  const NumberOnlyTextField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.obscureText,
    required this.enableTxtField,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 213, 211, 211)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            onChanged: (value) {
              onChanged?.call();
            },
            obscureText: obscureText,
            enabled: enableTxtField,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                RegExp('[0-9]+.?[0-9]*'),
              ),
            ],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
    

      border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

}
}
And now its working. I tried to print Value changed: when i write something in textfield. And it works !

Can you help me with the RegEX error. I want the input to allow only integer and double inputs

I tried ur code in chrome and its only get integer and double values as string. Can u write your error and code please

It accepts an alpabet. Try enter an input like 34b or 34.1t.
You will notice it accepts them

use this regex
RegExp(r'^\d+.?\d*')

u can use this RegExp(r'^\d+.?\d{0,2}') too if u want to allow only 2 decimal places after the dot

Worked like magic

Nice to hear that ! By the way can u accept my answer ? Thanks

As regard the NumberOnlyTextField, how did you re-use it cos it is not working from my end. Here is how I re-used it:
      NumberOnlyTextField(
        controller: amountController,
        onChanged: checkInputAmount(),
        hintText: 'Amount',
        obscureText: false,
        enableTxtField: true,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 10),


NumberOnlyTextField(
controller: controller,
hintText: 'Enter number',
obscureText: false,
enableTxtField: true,
onChanged: () {
print(controller.text);
},
),

maybe ur checkInputAmount() function have problem, can u pls try to print controller.text when onChanged or write checkInputAmount function's code

It worked when I used onChanged: () { checkInputAmount(); }, instead of onChanged: checkInputAmount(),


{void Function(String)? onChanged}
Type: void Function(String)?
Called when the user initiates a change to the TextField's value: when they have inserted or deleted text or reset the form.

you'll need to update your code as follows.
 final void Function(String)? onChanged;


 TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            onChanged: onChanged,
``


It didn't work still
